# Showing $f$ extends to a continuous map on a disk if $f$ has degree $0$

Tags: general-topology, homotopy-theory

How would you show that, if $f: S^1 \to S^1$ has degree $0$, (i.e. $\deg (f \circ \exp) = 0$ ) then $f$ extends to a continuous map $D \to S^1$?

Comment: Try to show that in this situation, your function $f$ is homotopic to a constant function.

Comment: Ok I think I've got that far because there is a theorem which states that $f \circ \exp$ is homotopic to $\exp (nt)$ for degree $n$ therefore $f \circ \exp$ is homotopic to $\exp(0) = 1$ a constant function. So if we set this homotopy as $G(t,u)$ we can define a homotopy $F(z,u): = G(\exp^{-1}(z),u)$ which is a homotopy from $f$ to the constant function $1$?

Comment: But now I can't see how we can define a function on the unit disk if this homotopy is only defined on $S^1$? Or am I missing something?

Comment: The domain of the homotopy is $[0,1]\times S^1$, and all points of the form $(1,x)$ have the same image...

Comment: Yes, you have to write it formally, but that's the idea, Now uses @Rhys suggestion to finish in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 -  You have a homotopy $H:[0,1]\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{S}$ which satisfies $$H(1,x)=f(x),\ \ \ \ \ H(0,x)=p$$

where $p\in\mathbb{S}$.

2 - There is an relation between $[0,1]\times\mathbb{S}$ and $\mathbb{D}$, what is this relation?